# Promise resolve not working but data is returned

Tags: javascript, api, .net-core, promise, es6-promise

I have this JS function that will get data from my API

```
function loadNotification() {
        const loadNotif = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Vendor/NotificationAPI/GetNotification",
                success: function (data) {
                    resolve(data)
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    reject(data)
                }
            });
        });

        loadNotif.then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            let template = document.querySelector('template#notif-template');
            var parent = document.querySelector('#notif-parent');

            parent.innerHTML = "";
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

                    clone.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class=\"fas fa-bell mr-2\"></i> " + item.Message;

                    parent.appendChild(clone);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("no comment");
                parent.innerHTML = "<p>No notifications.</p>";
            }
        }).catch((data) => {
            var parent = document.querySelector('#notif-parent');
            parent.innerHTML = "<p>No notifications.</p>";

        });
    }
```

But when I call that function in ready method of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        loadNotification();
    });
```

There is data returned but the what happened is, it throws and execute reject function.

Comment: the value of data in `.catch((data)` will probably tell you what your code is doing wrong - byt the way, unless you are using a very old version of jqueery, `$.ajax` returns a Promise-like result - so you can do `$.ajax({url: "/Vendor/NotificationAPI/GetNotification"}).then etc`

Comment: *"it throws"*: I cannot reproduce that behaviour. Follow the advise from Bravo.